# Colour no longer working in vim

Tags: terminal, color, vi

I've been using vim for as long as I can remember.  Never had a problem, until lately.  For no reason that I can see, colour has stopped working.  First noticed it when editing a Tex file, and I note that indentation is no longer coloured.

[image: color in vim]

I can open my .zshrc file, and indeed any other file, and the same.  No colour.

It's vim 8.2.1900 running on a Mac Mini (10.15.7 (19H15)).  I do not recall any destructive edits of my .vimrc file.

```
darren@mac ➜  ~  %{egrep "color|colour" .vimrc
ab cgfred <font color="red"></font>
ab cgfgreen <font color="green"></font>
ab cgfblue <font color="blue"></font>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: no changes or updates.  This is my .vimrc file (with personal stuff removed):

```
" vimrc settings


" vundle 

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" system settings

let g:auto_save = 1  " enable AutoSave on Vim startup


set mouse=a
set nocompatible
set showmode
autocmd BufEnter *.c,*.cpp,*.h,*.pl,*.pm,*.yml,*.sh,*.php,*.jar,*.sql set cindent
autocmd BufReadPre *.html* set
" autocmd BufReadPre /tmp/pico.*,mutt-* set filetype=mail
autocmd FileType css set smartindent crontab
set fileformats=unix,dos
set autoindent 
set tabstop=4
set splitbelow
set history=5000
set undolevels=10000
source ~/.vim/plugin/vimfootnotes.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/man.vim
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
" au BufWinLeave * mkview
" au BufWinEnter * silent loadview
set hidden
set ruler
set showmatch
set background=dark
syntax enable
set wrap
set textwidth=75
set sidescroll=1 
" language fr_FR.ISO_8859-15
syntax on

" abbreviations

" for LaTeX
"
" define the plugin
"
" set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
" let g:tex_flavor='latex'
" set sw=2

" for shell
ab sse /bin/echo


" international accent bindings
"
ab lAgrave &Agrave;
ab lagrave &agrave;
ab lCcedil &Ccedil;
ab lccedil &ccedil;
ab lEgrave &Egrave;
ab legrave &egrave;
ab lEacute &Eacute;
ab leacute &eacute;
ab lEtrema &Etrema;
ab letrema &etrema
ab lEcirc &Ecirc;
ab lecirc &ecirc;
ab litrema &itrema;
ab lOtrema &Otrema;
ab lotrema &otrema;
ab locirc &ocirc;
ab lUgrave &Ugrave;
ab lugrave &ugrave;
ab lucirc &ucirc;
ab ˚ &ucirc;
" ab leuro 



" C and Objective C Mappings
ab ccbc /**************************************************************************
ab ccec **************************************************************************/
ab ccmain int main(int argc, char** argv) {
ab ccpf printf(" ") ;

" mappings
imap !f <Plug>AddVimFootnote
imap !c <Plug>ReturnFromFootnote
map <F2> :!open .
map <F3> Vzf
imap <F3> <Esc> Vzf
map <F4> zo
imap <F4> <Esc> zo
map <F5> zf
imap <F5> <Esc> zf
map <F6> gqap <CR>
imap <F6> <Esc> gqap <CR>
map <F7> :next <CR>
imap <F7> <Esc> :next <CR>
map <F8> :previous <CR>
imap <F8> <Esc> :previous <CR>

" fold mappings
inoremap <F9> <C-O>za
nnoremap <F9> za
onoremap <F9> <C-C>za
vnoremap <F9> zf

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

" set  rtp+=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/vim/
" set laststatus=2
" set t_Co=256
```

Comment: What did change in the last days? Updates of any kind?

Comment: Nothing changed.  I've edited to include my .vimrc.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `vim` (I'm a `nano` guy myself) but as a suggestion to diagnose it...  Back up those files, rename them so `vim` only loads the most basic config then try enabling color to make sure it works.  The idea is to get to the most basic config, get it working, and go from there.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with vundle, but looking at their [quickstart guide](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start) shows that you've set up your vimrc incorrectly. Between `call vundle#begin()'` and `call vundle#end() ` should only be `Plugin 'git_URI'`'s. You've placed your entire vimrc setting between these two calls. Change this and see how things work.

Comment: I did that and it now looks like: 

call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'git_URI'

call vundle#end()            " required

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Comment: No, it didn't.  :-(  Appreciate it, though.